# how to build a calculator in GTK+?

Tags: c, gtk

what's the logic behind the calculator widget. i want to build it in gtk+.

Comment: have you tried writing any code and figuring it out for yourself?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Is this homework ?
Have to try thinking abut it, a calculator is a really simple programming exercise.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't listen to anyone who says that this is trivial.

Second, I'm going to assume that you really mean something like "How do I convert the user input to an internal expression structure which I can use to calculate the answer?". Well, Wikipedia has a good article ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser)) on converting infix (human readable) notation, which is what most modern calculators use (e.g you can write 1 + 2 instead of + 1 2), to the more computer appropriate polish (prefix) notation.

Third, if you don't know GTK+ yet, start [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think flagging beginners with even what seems as trivial question is not the correct way to introduce them to a community. I think the approach you have taken is very commendable.. +1 for u effort... :)